# $_FILES don't send name to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, file

**I used Forum and used this line:**

```
<form method="post" action="adduser.php">
Picture:<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" /></br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

**Also in adduser.php**

```
$image="pic/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"];

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(userid,username,name,family,email,city,gender,password,img) values(' ','$_POST[username]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[family]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[gender]','$password','$image');",$cn))
echo "New user added";
```

What's wrong? in database table just i see in img : **pic/**

Comment: Check if $_FILES not empty. And use filter_input to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use enctype attribute with form

```
<form method="post" action="adduser.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Also i have problem when i want update it. in edituser.php